# Rails CanCan only show data that user created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am using Devise for registering accounts and signing in/out. The next functionality I want to add is to only show the data entered for a given user. For instance, if I create a new "something" (a client in my case, at /clients/new), I only want the person who created that something to be able to view it. Right now, if I log in and create a new client, then log out and back in as a different user, I'm able to see the client I created as the other user. This should be restricted so that the author is the only one who can read, update and destroy their own clients.

I've watched Ryan Bate's [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) on CanCan 3 times now, but it seems to only touch on setting it up for different roles, and not for limiting content based on the author.

How can I go about this with CanCan?

My current `ability.rb` has nothing in it but an empty `initialize(user)` method.

I have tried this inside that method:

```
can :update, Client do |client|
    client.try(:user) == user
end
```

with

```
<% if can? :update, @client %> ... <% end %>
```

around the loop that displays the clients in the index view, but to no avail.

Comment: I think you want to reference current_user there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that filtering the results using CanCan is not an optimal solution.
If User 'has_many' Clients, then in your controller method just query for Users' clients:

```
@clients = current_user.clients
```

Comment: Duh, I knew it shouldn't have been that complicated. Got it working using your method. Building off of my question about authentication, what would prevent a user from going to say /clients/6 and viewing and editing (or even deleting) the client that a different user created? Is that where CanCan comes in? Or does Devise have that capability as well?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
def initialize(user)
  can :update, Client, :user_id => user.id
end
```

From [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)